# Rails bundler—how to specify a ruby version that you do not have installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I am using ruby 2.3, but I need my gems to also be compatible with 2.2

If I put `ruby '2.2'` in the Gemfile, bundler complains that my ruby version doesn't match what it says in the gemfile.

Is there any way to specify the ruby version, and ignore what version I am currently using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the `ruby 2.2` version and use that when running the code. For using multiple rubies on the same machine you should use some sort of ruby environment manager.

Have a look at [uru](https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru/src/master/) (best option in Windows) or [rvm](https://rvm.io/) (my personal preference in Linux)

Comment: I was trying to avoid installing 2.2 (lots of trouble downgrading commandlinetools and openssl), but you're right it was impossible to do any other way